# How to display time from JSON in HorizontalPicker Flutter?

Tags: flutter

[image]

I would like to create a scrollable horizontal picker exactly like the picture shown above to display the time stored in JSON. However, I faced the error of 'Invalid double 12:00PM'.

**Or is it has any other solutions to create this scrollable horizontal timeline in Flutter?**

Below is my code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 120,
          child: HorizontalPicker(
              minValue: double.parse(data.schedule.delivery[0].time.toString()),
              maxValue:  double.parse(data.schedule.delivery[data.schedule.delivery.length].time.toString()),
              divisions: data.schedule.delivery.length,
              showCursor: false,
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              activeItemTextColor: Colors.black,
              passiveItemsTextColor: Colors.grey,
              onChanged: (double value) {
                setState(() {
                  holder = value.toString();
                });
              }
          ),
        ),
        );
  }
```

Above is JSON data
[image]

Below is the error displayed:
[image]

Comment: can you show us the json data as well?

Comment: edited already.

Answer (score 0):

Your time is not a valid double literal because of the "PM" and ":", hence it cannot be parsed into a double value.

[Dart Double.parse method doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/double/parse.html)

Comment: If I want to display the data, is it possible? Can you help me? I'm new to Flutter

Comment: It is possible. is your time data already in order when provided or do you have to reorder it?

Comment: the time data already in order when provided

Comment: how can i do, if I would like straight away to display the data as String?

Comment: I dont think the widget allows you to input string. From what i can see you can supply a suffix but the data for min and max values can only be double (number).

Comment: ermm. Ok, thank you.